# paypal objective c library

Tags: objective-c, ios

I use Mobile Payment Libraries for iOS PayPal intergration and when I lunch the demo example run on iOS 4.3 simulator only but when lunch on iOS 5 simulator I got this error.

```
SimpleDemo[3594:ef03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString rangeOfString:options:range:locale:]: nil argument' </i>
```

Comment: Paste the code that does this `[__NSCFConstantString rangeOfString:options:range:locale:]`